# What are the security implications of using sandboxed mode and loading scripts from a trusted source?

Tags: javascript, security, reactjs, google-chrome-app

We are building a chrome web app that connects to a remote server. The remote server will be serving custom javascript files that are stored in the database. These files will be injected into code for working.

To be specific we are using ReactJS framework and we are injecting custom React components into this application based on the given route.

The chrome app with a sandboxed window works normally. However, I am trying to figure out the security implications of using a sandboxed app that connects to a remote server. What kind of security problems can this approach create?

I also want to know if there is a way to make that chrome app only loads JS files that are coming from a specific IP address. In extensions it is possible but I haven't been able to find anything for chrome packaged apps.

Comment: Have you read `permissions` documentation for `manifest.json`? _"However, I am trying to figure out the security implications of using a sandboxed app that connects to a remote server."_ Not sure what you mean? What implications are different from other application on web?

Comment: Going through [WebSockets - An Introduction](https://gist.github.com/subudeepak/9897212) might help. As mentioned in that post, 
> JavaScript was getting more powerful and browsers were relaxing their limitations due to the presence of a sandbox. Imagine the power the hacker would get if a chrome app or Firefox extension (which have access to even more powerful functionality) were to be affected. Note that WebSockets itself is not a problem and it is highly appreciated. The only non-logical problem seems to be the lack of enforcement of the same-origin policy.

Comment: Aside from that, you may want to also check the [reviews](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/answer/What-are-Google-Chromes-security-features) on the security features of Google Chrome and see if it will help.